# mvc4 razor webpages sporadically populating dropdowns after converting to jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am in the process of converting several working asp.net mvc 4 (razor) webpages over to jquery mobile and I am seeing some things I don't understand.

The @Html.DropDownListFor don't always populate.....I have inspected the html using firebug and SOMETIMES when the webpage comes up its dropdown has no values...but it is sporadic...I hate sporadic problems....it is driving me up the wall...

Here is the controller...I have checked when the problem is happening...it is always generating the data and sending it....

```
public ActionResult SelectWorkCenter()
{
    SelectWorkCenterInputModel model = new SelectWorkCenterInputModel();
    model.WorkCenterList = wcService.GetWorkCenters().OrderBy(p=>p.WorkCenterName).ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

Here is the web page with the dropdown that is sporadically working:

```
@using TBS.Etracs.Web.Main.Areas.WorkCenter.Models
@model SelectWorkCenterInputModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Select Work Center";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SelectWorkOrder", "Mobile", new {Model.SelectedWorkCenterID }))
{          
    <div class="divTable">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell"></div>
            <div class="divTableCell">[WorkCenterName (#Vehicles)]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell"><label><strong> WorkCenter</strong></label></div>
            <div class="divTableCell">   
                @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.SelectedWorkCenterID,
                                     new SelectList(Model.WorkCenterList, "WorkCenterID", "WorkCenterName"),
                                     "Select a Work Center",
                                     new { Class    = "dropdownstyle",
                                           onchange = "this.form.submit();",
                                           style    = "width:220px; height: 40px;font-size: 1.2em;font-weight:bold"
                                         })   
                </div> 
        </div>
    </div>    
     <input type="submit" value="Back" onclick="history.back(); return false;" style="margin-right: 20px" />
}
```

I am in the process of converting the  from a divTable over to data-role....and the wierd thing is sometimes this after I convert to data-role things improve and other times it makes the problems worse....

I don't understand why converting to jquery mobile would have any impact on this.....

The other problem I am having is that my buttons don't always fire events back to my controllers now that I have converted over to jquery mobile.... I don't know if this is a related problem or not...

Any ideas what I have missed?

Comment: OK....I was wrong the HTML IS BEING POPULATED with Select data....but the dropdown just does not work....  So now I am even more confused....Why won't the drop down show the select values????

Answer (score 0):

More details.....Now that I know more of what is going on I am seeing that this question has been asked before .... I still have not solved the problem, but it does not seem to be the most likey problem that I have seen in other post .... Here is my model which .... this should be correct (as it was working)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using TBS.Etracs.Web.Main.Models;

namespace TBS.Etracs.Web.Main.Areas.WorkCenter.Models
{
    public class SelectWorkCenterInputModel
    {
        public int SelectedWorkCenterID { get; set; }
        public List<AssignedWorkCenter> WorkCenterList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
AssignedWorkCenter is an EF generated type with values of
     System.Int32 WorkCenterID
     System.String WorkCenterName
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok...I don't understand it , but here is the solution....

The problem was with the specifiction of the Style inside the dropDownListFor....By eliminating the Style line everything works...

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.SelectedWorkOrderCode,   
                         new SelectList (Model.WorkOrders, "WorkCenterID", "WorkOrderCodeDesc"),   
                                                        "Select a Work Order",     
                                            new { id       = "WorkCenterID",
                                                Class    = "dropdownstyle" })
```